# Extract values from an Object which contains a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a JavaScript Object which contains a form. when i print the object it was as bellow.

```
<form action=\"https://www.example.com/api/tty/1p0/user/pwc\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_self\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" >

<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"ppw_version\" value=\"TTR-1p0\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"custom_source\" value=\"98\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"resource_url_id\" value=\"xxx-xx-xxx-xxxx\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"lis_person_id\" value=\"xxxxxx\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"oauth_nonce\" value=\"xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"oauth_timestamp\" value=\"1461584435\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"oauth_consumer_key\" value=\"xxxxx\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"oauth_signature_method\" value=\"HMAC-SHA1\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"oauth_version\" value=\"1.0\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"oauth_signature\" value=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=\" />
<input type=\"submit\" style=\"\" value=\"\" />

</form>
```

I want to extract "ppw_version" value from that object and assign it to a variable. Is it possible in Java Script ?

```
Data = "<form action=\"https://www.example.com/api/tty/1p0/user/pwc\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_self\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" ></form>"
```

and from "Data" i want to extract  "ppw_version"
Thanks

Comment: Where is the object?

Comment: The example `Data` string has the form but no content. There is no `ppw_version` to read!

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery

```
var $form = $("form");
var ppwVersion = $form.find("[name='ppw_version']").val();
```

Comment: To be precise i want to extract data from the object which contains the form.

Data = "<form action=\"https://www.example.com/api/tty/1p0/user/pwc\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_self\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" ></form>"

and from "Data" i want to extract  "ppw_version"

Comment: @PeterB Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on earlier replies I sense that perhaps this will help:

```
var $form = $(Data); // If Data is a FORM object, then now $form is a jquery-wrapper around that object
var ppwVersion = $form.find("[name='ppw_version']").val();
```